# MySQL 5.7 - Update parent records with oldest created child

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

My goal is to create an `UPDATE` statement that updates parent records' `default_page_id` to be that of the earliest child created.

The parent/child is 2 levels max/deep limited by the UI; the `parent_id` column denotes the parent of the record, the `type` value of `root` further simplifies what the root/parents are.

I have a dbfiddle with a DDL/DML here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=994d9bf3b20b3bbab21547d4334fc0e7

Ultimately my `SELECT` which I am trying to get right will become my `UPDATE` is here but uses `MIN(id)` which wouldn't be feasible as `id` is a `char(36)` and thus `id` does not autoincrement; I have tried to use `MIN(created)` but am missing the necessary updates to the GROUP BY in order to solve this and would appreciate another eye!

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            test_pages.id
        FROM
            test_pages
        WHERE
            test_pages.default_page_id is null
        and test_pages.type = "root"
    ) as a
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        parent_id ,
        MIN(id) AS id
    from
        test_pages
    WHERE
        test_pages.type = "container"
    GROUP BY
        parent_id
) as b ON b.parent_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SQL (SELECT):

If I understand the issue correctly, the following sql might be helpful:

```sql
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.default_page_id,
    r.type,
    r.title,
    c.parent_id AS container_parent_id,
    c.id AS container_id
FROM
    test_pages AS r
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            parent_id,
            id
        FROM
            test_pages
        WHERE
            type = "container"
            AND created = (
                SELECT
                    MIN(created)
                FROM
                    test_pages AS tp
                WHERE
                    type = "container"
                    AND test_pages.parent_id = tp.parent_id
            )
    ) AS c ON r.id = c.parent_id
WHERE
    type = "root";
```

### SQL (UPDATE):

The update sql is as follows:

```sql
UPDATE
    test_pages AS t
SET
    t.default_page_id = (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    parent_id,
                    id
                FROM
                    test_pages
                WHERE
                    type = "container"
                    AND created = (
                        SELECT
                            MIN(created)
                        FROM
                            test_pages AS tp
                        WHERE
                            type = "container"
                            AND test_pages.parent_id = tp.parent_id
                    )
            ) AS c
        WHERE
            t.id = c.parent_id
    );
```

### Output:

After updating, the `test_pages` looks like the following table:

| id | version_id | parent_id | default_page_id | type | title | created | modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jf2039jf932032f | 2 | abc1212312efff | nan | container | Child Page 2 | 2022-02-23 23:25:41 | nan |
| 7eajiefaeiaeaeleailje | 2 | nan | 8efjaliejfaelfjael | root | Root Page A | nan | nan |
| 8efjaliejfaelfjael | 2 | 7eajiefaeiaeaeleailje | nan | container | Child Page Again 1 | 2022-02-04 23:26:01 | nan |
| abc1212312efff | 2 | nan | ejejejejejej | root | Root Page | nan | nan |
| ejejejejejej | 2 | abc1212312efff | nan | container | Child Page 1 | 2022-02-03 23:26:01 | nan |
| fefeee9f9e9fee | 2 | nan | nan | root | Root Page With No Children | nan | nan |
| jklfjealkjlfajfl | 2 | 7eajiefaeiaeaeleailje | nan | container | Child Page Again 2 | 2022-02-07 23:25:41 | nan |

### Note:

If there are more than one container with different `id` but with exactly the same `created` under the same parent container, you might get an error as follows. In this case, you have to write additional code. So be careful please.

```sh
Query 1: Subquery returns more than 1 row
```